# Why localStorage.getItem always return string?

Tags: javascript, typescript

It's weird. I find localstorage.getItem's type in lib.dom.d.ts returns 'string | null', but when I use it in my app it always return string
Why?

Comment: It returns null only when you target a key that has not been set, have you tried to get such a key? You can try for instance `localStorage.getItem(Math.random())`

Answer (score 10):

Because that is how it is:

> The keys and the values are always strings

See the doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: ... and if you target a non-existing item, you get `null` for `getItem()`, therefore the TypeScript annotation defines an union type of `string` and `null`.

Answer (score 3):

If you use json object in the `localStorage` then you can use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` method .

To store object in localStorage ,

```
localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(user));
```

To get object from localStorage ,

```
user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
```

Here , you will get the object rather than string .